# Trying to group repeated x values, and find the mean of the y values associated with these repeats

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas. I wrote this script that does what I want but is definitely not optimized at all. Basically, I find all x repeats in namearray, take the average of the associated y values, replace the y value of the first row with the average and remove all repeated x value's rows except for the first row. Effectively, on a graph, I remove points that appear stacked on top of each other and only plot the average produced instead.

```
cats = np.unique(name_array[selected_x].values)
for j in cats:
    rows_cat = name_array[name_array[selected_x] == j]
    first_row = rows_cat.iloc[[0],:]

    avg = rows_cat[selected_y].mean()
    first_row[selected_y] = avg

    name_array = name_array[name_array[selected_x] != j]
    name_array = name_array.append(first_row,ignore_index=True)
```

This is the script I am trying to replace it by. However, it does not work and I am not sure why. I am trying to group by the x values like before, and replace the y value of the newly grouped x with the mean:

```
name_array[selected_y] = name_array.groupby(selected_x)[selected_y].mean()
```

This approach seems much simpler, more readable, and efficient. Any ideas why it is not performing the same function?

Edit:

An input example:

| date | state | new_cases | new deaths | days_since_date | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-24 | PA | 500 | 200 | 4 | etc. |
| 2021-03-25 | PA | 300 | 300 | 4 | etc. |
| 2021-03-26 | PA | 400 | 100 | 2 | etc. |
| 2021-03-27 | PA | 200 | 200 | 1 | etc. |

say selected_y is new_cases, and selected_x is days_since_date.
What I want is, this:

| date | state | new_cases | new deaths | days_since_date | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-24 | PA | 400 | 200 | 4 | etc. |
| 2021-03-26 | PA | 400 | 100 | 2 | etc. |
| 2021-03-27 | PA | 200 | 200 | 1 | etc. |

Essentially, group where it repeats in selected_x column, take the mean of the associated values in selected_y column, but do not take the mean of the other columns.

The reason being, the date is not a datetime type, so I cannot see taking the mean of that as something that will actually mean anything, and in the grand scheme of things I do not care if the date is averaged. Same applies to state, you cannot get the mean of a string, unless you do some type of ASCII math or something, which is not what I want either.

Comment: Can you share the input data set

Comment: as well as the expected output:)

Comment: Done, let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

```
data.groupby(['x']).mean()['y']
```

In this way you group the data based on `x` find the mean of all columns associated to that group by calling `.mean` and the slice the column `y` that you need.

Comment: Reposted the data I have, some of the columns are strings, so I believe this answer would have to be adjusted to account for that.

Comment: Yes, it functions oddly. For some reason it removes all but two points on my graph. So I will mess with it a bit, initial thought is the string columns act oddly when the mean is taken.